# Analytic function on a unit disc

Tags: complex-analysis

Does there exist an analytic function on unit disc s.t. $\left|f\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\right)-\dfrac{(-1)^n}{n^2}\right|<\dfrac{1}{n^3}$ for all $n\geqslant 2$.

I am thinking of finding an analytic function f such that f(1/n)=(-1)^n/n^2, then conclude that the statement is true.

I need your suggestions.

Comment: Here, you need to show some of your own efforts. Otherwise the question (however interesting, and I think it is interesting) may be closed.

Answer (score 1):

One can easily check that $f(z)=az^k+\mathcal{O}(z^{k+1})$ for $z\to 0$ for any integer $k\geq0$ and $a\in\mathbb{C}-\{0\}$ is in conflict with your condition hence it is impossible (just substitute $f$ into your absolute value with the above expression for $f$ and estimate).